# Org-mode latex environment in drawer

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I use a custom LaTeX environment that creates a quotation box on export. A sample code looks like this:

```
* Org-mode heading

Here is a witty quote from a witty chap:

\begin{fancyquote}

Witty quote!

\end{fancyquote}
```

To maintain readability of the org-file itself, I would rather use something like this:

```
* Org-mode heading

Here is a witty quote from a witty chap:

** Witty quote :ignore:
:LATEXENVIRONMENT:
:PREFIX: \begin{fancyquote}
:POSTFIX: \end{fancyquote}
:END:

    Witty quote!
```

On export the LaTeX code in `PREFIX` and `POSTFIX` is then wrapped around the content of the heading, the heading itself not being exported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use special blocks:

```
#+begin_fancyquote
 Something very witty!
#+end_fancyquote
```

Comment: The # at the line start was swallowed up for the begin and end directives.

Comment: I accept this as a better answer than mine, because my link solution is less useful when dealing with a lot of content within the environment. Thanks for pointing out this feature.

Answer (score 3):

**I. The custom link type approach**

One can define a custom link type, for example `latexenv` with `org-add-link-type` that wraps a specified latex environment around the text:

1. Definition of the new link type with a babel code block:

   ```
   #+name: latex-env
   #+begin_src emacs-lisp   
   (org-add-link-type
    "latexenv" nil
      (lambda (path desc format)
        (when(eq format 'latex)
         (format "\\begin{%s}%s\\end{%s}" path desc path))))
   #+end_src
   ```
2. Use the link type with the desired LaTeX environment, for example `fancyquote`:

   ```
   [[latexenv:fancyquote][This text is within the environment fancyquote]]
   ```

**II. The special block solution**

As @éric pointed out in his answer, org-mode allows to use special blocks. Here is an example with a fictional environment `fancyquote` with parameters:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: options: [Here]{There}{That}
#+begin_fancyquote 
Something witty!
#+end_fancyquote
```

This will export to LaTeX as:

```
\begin{fancyquote}[Here]{There}{That}
  Something witty!
\end{fancyquote}
```

Comment: The correct sintax in #+ATTR_LATEX: :options [Here]{There}{That}

Comment: correct syntax! :-) Always happens.